# How to escape special characters in CNTK Text Reader?

Tags: cntk

For a reader such as this reading a file in CTF format,

```
     query         = StreamDef(field='S0', shape=vocab_size,  is_sparse=True),
     intent        = StreamDef(field='S1', shape=num_intents, is_sparse=True),  
     slot_labels   = StreamDef(field='S2', shape=num_labels,  is_sparse=True)
```

How do I escape special charachter such as "|" if it is a token? 
I am getting an warning for the line in the middle where the token itself is "|"

48155   |S0 196:1 |# -  |S2 0:1 |# None

48155   |S0 18217:1 |# |    |S2 0:1 |# None

48155   |S0 3152:1 |# Cindy |S2 0:1 |# None

I can remove these when creating the CFT file, but I was wondering how we  can handle this. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The pipe can be escaped by appending the hash symbol to it: `|# this is a CTF comment with an escaped pipe: '|#'`

Answer (score 0):

You can also map pipes to another word or character that does not appear in your corpus. I typically replace pipes with .